# How to make a "Force feedback" effect with physics?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

So I made this neat animation by Cell Fracturing a sphere then rendering the physics.
[image: animated gif]
Looks nice, however I want there to be an "Upwards Kick" so the fractured pieces don't just flop down on impact. Some of them should bounce up (in a realistic sense). How would I go about creating this effect in blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the physics panel and have a similar setup for every shard like i did here with this sphere[image]

dynamic
The setup for the floor is the same exept one thing disable dynamic in the physics tab.
So basically what you were missing (if im correct) its that you didnt setup a bounciness for your objects ;)
Also you may need adjust the solver iterations (in the scene tab in rigid body world section)(this will make physics more accurate)

Comment: Also mess around with the settings a bit more to achieve better results ;)
And if you upload the video i'd like to know how it turned out

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Bl5Pw9yNGH4    Not sure how the animations turned out how they did but whatever

Comment: @JoshSilveous Really nice job ;) well done.